# Dictionary with lists: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have such a method:

```
def satisfied(self, assignment: Dict[str, List[str]]) -> bool:
        row: str = self.variables[0]
        column: str = self.variables[1]

        # If either variable is not in the assignment then it is not
        # yet possible for them to conflict
        if row not in assignment or column not in assignment:
            return True

        row_num: int = int(row[3:])
        col_num: int = int(column[3:])

        return assignment[row][col_num] == assignment[col][row_num] # here is this error
```

and it is called like this:

```
def revise_during_search(self, x: V, y: V, value: D, constraint: Constraint[V, D], purged_values: Dict[V, List[D]]) -> bool:
        revised: bool = False
        for val in self.domains[y]: # val is also type of D
            if not constraint.satisfied({x: value, y: val}):
            ... something happens here
```

So as you can see `V` is `str` nad `D` is `List[str]`.

When `satisfied` method gets called I get such error:

```
File "file.py", line 87, in satisfied
    return assignment[row][col_num] == assignment[col][row_num]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

But I don't understand, because when I call `assignment[row]`, where `row` is a string it gives me a `List` and I use `col_num` which is a number to get a specific value.

Comment: In Python, strings are lists and can be accessed the same way. I think you should try like an if statement where the condition is to not be a list. Just an idea.

Comment: @MartínSchere but I used strings as keys many times before and I've never seen this error.

Comment: In this part of the code `assignment[col][row_num]` where is the variable `col` defined and what type is it? you dont show any variable in your code named `col`

Comment: can you say what type has `self.variables` ?

Comment: @kederrac `self.variables` is a `List[V]` which in this case is `List[str]`.

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, you are right I misspelled `column` for `col`. I haven't noticed even though I've been looking on this for a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

most probably `self.variables[0]` or `self.variables[1]` is a list and you can not use this line:

```
if row not in assignment or column not in assignment:
```

ex of search of a list in a dict:

```
[123] in {1: 2}
```

output:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

---

also, you may check your variable `col` which it is not defined in your function, this may be a `list`

Comment: But this line doesn't give an error. This `return assignment[row][col_num] == assignment[col][row_num]` does.

Comment: I edited the question's error code, it should be clear now. Sorry for that missunderstanding.

Comment: @Karol  what is `col` is that a list?

Comment: I've not realized that  I misspelled column for col. I haven't noticed even though I've been looking at this for a long time. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: so `col` is your issue ?

Comment: Yes :/ and I'm super embarrassed that I haven't seen that